# how to convert this.setState({ [section]: y }) to useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am just converting my class to function component. There in a function I want to convert into state.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      sections: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
      currentSection: 1
    };
  }
onItemLayout = ({ nativeEvent: { layout: { x, y, width, height } } }, section) => {
    // setting each items position
    
     this.setState({ [section]: y });
    
  };
```

I just converted state to

```
const [sections] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState(1);
```

but could not understand that how to convert

```
this.setState({ [section]: y });
```

to function component.

Comment: You can also use three states: `const [sections, setSections] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])`, `const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState(1)`, and `const [positions, setPositions] = useState({})`. To set positon: `setPositions(prev => ({ ...prev, [section]: y }))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
   sections: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
   currentSection: 1
});

const onItemLayout = ({ nativeEvent: { layout: { y } } }, section) => {
   setState(currentState => ({
      ...currentState,
      [section]: y
   }))
};

const updateSection = (newSection) => {
   setState(currentState => ({
      ...currentState,
      currentSection: newSection
   }))
};
```

Comment: then how to update currentSection in useState ... sorry I am new to react

Comment: `setState((currentState) => ({ ...currentState, currentSection: 2 }))`

Comment: You can do it as @dcangulo suggested. I added an example to the code.

Comment: thanks @DejanSandic. soled the issue ... +1